# Packages in java - necessary?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just read a java book and it stated that the package statement is optional in Java. So I wrote a code without the package statement in Intellij IDEA but it doesn't work unless the package statement is provided in the code.  It was just a hello world statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package statement is optional, yes. However, classes in the default package (which is where they go if you have no package statement) have various limitations. You presumably ran into one.

Generally, whilst it's optional, don't write java code without package statements.

Comment: You did't writed the limitations of an project without package.

Comment: Is this simply a problem with the IDE insisting on a package definition when the language does not need it?

Comment: @another-dave IntelliJ does not require a class to be in a package. That said, it's a very bad idea in general to not use packages.

Comment: @another-dave The OP said it 'doesnt work' and was non-specific as to what that means. The things that it might be are near endless. I merely pointed at that there are various limitations and, given that it 'didnt work', OP presumably ran into one. Let's not assume anything about what 'isnt working': Let's not assume it's intellij blindly not accepting it, for example.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - Fair enough comment. As a programmer, I'm just professionally conditioned to diagnose problems in the face of inadequate supporting data :-)